# How do I add php-svg-lib to dompdf so I can use svgs in my pdf

Tags: php, pdf, svg

I use dompdf to make pdfs from html.
It works great apart from the fact that you cannot show svgs.
Apparently dompdf 0.7.0 has the ability to show svgs, but you need a special library called php-svg-lib. I know I have to use the img tags to show an svg in pdf which is fine, but it keeps saying "unknown image"

So I downloaded the php-svg-lib library from the github, but I have no idea how to install it.

My question is how do I install php-svg-lib into dompdf so that I can use svgs in my pdf documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that php-svg-lib comes with version 0.1 of dompdf.

You can update it via composer. Once composer is installed:

1. Open a cmd prompt window.
2. Enter the dompdf folder and type composer show. This shows you what version of the libraries are installed.
3. Type either `composer update` or `composer install` to update all libraries.